# Scraping one tweet per user using snscrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, tweets

I'm using `snscrape.modules.twitter.TwitterSearchScraper()` function to scrape tweets for a specific location and time interval. The code is the following one:

```py
loc ='40.4165, -3.70256, 10km'
query = 'geocode:"{}" since:2020-03-15 until:2020-05-01'.format(loc)
tweets_list = []

for tweet in sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query).get_items():
      if i==100:
        break
      tweets_list.append([tweet.date, tweet.user.username, tweet.user.id, tweet.coordinates, tweet.rawContent])
```

My question is if there is a way to get only one tweet per user, because by running the above code some users are repeated.

Comment: You could check if the `tweet.user.id` exists *before* adding it to your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the `tweet.user.id` exists *before* adding it to your list.

Here, I added a new list (*called `tweets_user_ids`*) for store the values from `tweet.user.id` and add the *tweet* in the `tweets_list` list variable if the `tweet.user.id` does not exists on the new list.

Code:

```
import snscrape
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter

loc ='40.4165, -3.70256, 10km'
query = 'geocode:"{}" since:2020-03-15 until:2020-05-01'.format(loc)
tweets_list = []
max_amount_of_tweets = 100
tweets_user_ids = [] # Lists of tweets user ids - this is for check and avoid duplicates.
i = 0 # I suppose this is an incremental value.

for tweet in sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query).get_items():
  # Add the ids to a separate list: 
  if (len(tweets_user_ids) == 0):
    tweets_user_ids.append(tweet.user.id)
  
  # Check if the id is not already added, then, add the data: 
  if (tweet.user.id not in tweets_user_ids):
    tweets_user_ids.append(tweet.user.id)
    tweets_list.append([tweet.date, tweet.user.username, tweet.user.id, tweet.coordinates, tweet.rawContent])
    i+=1 # Increment.
    
  # Break the loop when the max amount of tweets is reached.
  if (i == max_amount_of_tweets):
    break
print(tweets_list)
```